# How can i get an object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

At the entrance I have such an array with objects.
Function that converts an incoming array of objects into an object. 
Using the function, I need to bring it to this form.

```
var array = [ 
   { k1:v1 },
   { k2:v2 },
   { k3:v3 }
];

function arrayToObject(array) { return object }

var object = { 
    v1: k1,
    v2: k2,
    v3: k3, 
}
```

Comment: There are so many answers out there that can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array for example

Comment: Wait, do you really need to swap keys with values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach` loop

```js
var array = [ 
   { k1:'v1' },
   { k2:'v2' },
   { k3:'v3' }
]

function a()
{
var obj={};
array.forEach((e)=>obj[e[Object.keys(e)[0]]]=Object.keys(e)[0])
console.log(obj)
}
a();
```

Comment: Could you explain this piece of code?
@AshayMandwarya

Comment: The forEach loop is used to itearte over an array one by one. the e on every iteration represents the object in the array. `Object.keys(e)[0]` this gives us an array of all the keys of the object e. There is only one so we use [0] to get that key. We access the value corresponding to that key using e[key] we get the key from the above `Object.keys(e)[0]` accessing this gives us the value corresponding to that key. Now we have the value, inside the empty object `obj` we make this as the key again using [] `obj[key]` and this key is given the value of  `Object.keys(e)[0]` which is the key itself

Comment: Thus interchanging the key and value. Hope you understood

Comment: T u so much @AshayMandwarya

Answer (score 2):

You could taske [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and spread the reversed objects.

```js
var array = [ { k1: 'v1' }, { k2: 'v2' }, { k3: 'v3' }],

object = Object.assign(...array.map(o => Object
    .entries(o)
    .reduce((r, [k, v]) => Object.assign(r, { [v] : k }), {})
));

console.log(object);
```

Comment: He wants the keys reversed, apparently (might be a mistake however...). Edit: note that I didn't downvote the answer though!

Comment: The keys of the returned object must be the values of the elements of the original array

Comment: @ИлияПолторацкий, it should do it now.

Comment: But why the complexity? Because you can? Have a look at my answer for something simple and readable

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries()` and `.reduce()` methods to get the desired output:

```js
const array = [ 
   { k1:'v1' },
   { k2:'v2' },
   { k3:'v3' }
];

const obj = Object.entries(
    array.reduce((r, c) => Object.assign(r, c), {})
).reduce((r, [k, v]) => (r[v] = k, r), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) over each array element.

```js
var array = [ 
   { k1: 'v1' },
   { k2: 'v2' },
   { k3: 'v3' }
]

var obj = array.reduce((obj, item) => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => obj[item[key]] = key)
   
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: You mean using a `forEach`?

Comment: We've had that conversation before. I don't like your approach. I like my transformations to be done in one-go.

Comment: It's not an insult. I really think you're confused as to what side-effect means.

Comment: Sorry but I still think you're confused as to what side-effect means. Your example modifies a variable outside its local environment which is the very definition of a side-effect. I don't agree on `noobs do not need clever` either. They can click the links I gave them and learn about `reduce`, which is how I learned about it as well.

Comment: Ok let's agree to disagree, which for the record I do disagree with all your points.

Comment: Yeah trust me, I would hate that as well.

Answer (score 0):

And another one:

```
 const result = {};

 for(const [[key, value]] of array.map(Object.entries))
   result[value] = key;
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why the other answers go through hoops to make this as clever as possible.

I find this more readable. I am not using reduce because I find the word misleading. A simple forEach makes more sense to me

```js
const array = [ 
   { k1:'v1' },
   { k2:'v2' },
   { k3:'v3' }
];
let newObj={};

array.forEach((obj) => { 
  let key = Object.keys(obj)[0];
  newObj[obj[key]]=key;
})  
console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score -2):

your answer..

```js
var array = [
  { k1: v1 },
  { k2: v2 },
  { k3: v3 }
];

function arrayToObject(array) {
  obj = {};
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    o = array[i];
    key = Object.keys(o)[0];
    obj.key = o.key;
  }
  return obj;
}


console.log(arrayToObject(array))
```

Comment: Your code does not run - and when the error is fixed it does not produce the correct result.